# Music not playing in executable .Jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am using the JLayer MP3 Library to play an MP3 file in my program.

My teacher told us to use something like:

```
imageLabel = new JLabel(ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("filename.jpg")));
```

to load our music and images if we are going to export our programs as an executable .jar file. However, when  I do that with my music, I get the error message "The constructor MP3(URL) is undefined".

This is the part of code from my Homepage class:

```
//Play music 
MP3 mp3 = new MP3(this.getClass().getResource("YGSA.mp3"));
mp3.play();
```

This is the part of code from the MP3 class:

```
public class MP3 {
private String filename;
private Player player; 

// constructor that takes the name of an MP3 file
public MP3(String filename) {
this.filename = filename;

}

public String toString() {
return filename;
}

public void close() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

// play the MP3 file to the sound card
public void play() {
try {
    FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(filename);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    player = new Player(bis);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
    System.out.println(e);
}

// run in new thread to play in background
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    try { player.play(); }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}.start();
}
```

Are there any alternative ways to load music so that it will work in a .jar? Everything else works fine. It's only the music that's acting up.

I've been stuck on this for some time, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the resource URL try using resource as stream. Bellow are some changes that you will need to do. Try to refactor the variable names.

Firt change your call to use getResourceAsStream instead of getResource. 
Second, Change your MP3 class constructor to receive a InputStream instead of String (also change your fileName variable type to InputStream. Refact their name here.

Finally, change your play method to use the inputStream.

```
MP3 mp3 = new MP3(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("YGSA.mp3"));
mp3.play();


 public MP3(InputStream filename) {
   this.filename = filename;

 }
public void play() {
try {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    player = new Player(bis);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH FOR THE SWIFT REPLY! I tried it again and now it works perfectly.